# Supabase Storage

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

If I drag and drop a jpg image from my hard drive to Supabase Storage Public No RLS bucket then everything works (i.e. there is a preview thumb, and when I get the url path and paste it into browser the photo is displayed.

If I use the same photo and upload as:

const { data, error } = await this.supabase.storage.from('report-photos').upload(name, file,{contentType:'image/jpeg'});

The insert is successful, but there is no image preview and pasting the provided url from Supabase just shows a blank page with small white square, although the bucket list view shows it as a image/jpg file and it has data.
[image: Supabase Bucket file preview with no preview]

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your code? E.g. what's the type of the variable `file`, and how is the `file` variable instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { decode } from 'base64-arraybuffer'

const image = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA='

const base64 = image.split('base64,')[1]

const { data, error } = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .upload('public/avatar1.png', decode(base64), {
    contentType: 'image/png'
  })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).